# How to exclude signed jars from pom.xml in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

When I try to create a `jar` for my project, I get the following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

I think my project contains several signed jars from google but when I try to fix this problem by removing the signature from the `META-INF`, the problem persists. I think I'm not correctly excluding signed jars from my `pom.xml` file but I don't know how to do it properly.

Can you help me with this problem? Thank you in advance
(I'm using IntelliJ)

My pom.xml file is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>VSCloud_Server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- local repository "lib"-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/hsqldb/hsqldb.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sqltool</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqltool</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/hsqldb/sqltool.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- maven repository "mvnrepository.com"-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev105-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Great! I found the answer and it works for me.

My pom.xml file is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>VS_Cloud_Server</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- maven repository "mvnrepository.com"-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/sqltool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqltool</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev105-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>VS_Cloud_Server</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Make this jar executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>CervoEngine_17.StartingPoint</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```